# Can we pay zakaat money or other donations for purpose of planting trees specifically?

Tags: zakat, sadaqah

Assalam o alaikum:

I just saw a man advertising his account details **to get donations of ramadan for planting trees**, and he says it is to make our envirenment better etc.

**Now I am confused if ramazan donations, zakaat specifically, and other donations like sadaqaat in general be given to such purposes? And will we get reward from Allah for these donations.**

Note: Please provide the answers with full reference from Quran and Sahi ahadees.

Jazakallah

Answer (score 4):

At first there is two terms that needs to be clarified: Sadakat (donations) and Zakat.

- **Sadakat** (or donations) are any amount of money you pay for any charity purpose. To poor people, to public welfare, even to rich people some times: you donate for public schools that educate people regardless of their financial state, or hospitals that treat the public masses without paying any fees, and so on.
- **Zakat** are specified ratio of money paid at specified time to specified recipients. There are several types of Zakat, I'll mention two here due to the purpose of question:

  1. **Zakat Almal** is 2.5% of your liquid savings that remains in your possession for a complete lunar (Hijri) year. And is paid for poor people and other recipients all mentioned in [Surat Altauba, Ayah 60](http://legacy.quran.com/9/60).
  2. **Zakat Alfetr** is about 3 kilos of the most common food in your country: wheat, rice, corn, and so on depending on your country. It is paid in the month of Ramadan to poor people only.

So the answer is: if by "donations of Ramadan" you mean Zakat Alfetr, then no it doesn't go for trees, you go as described in case 2. If you mean Zakat Almal which you want to pay during Ramadan to get more Hasanat (good deeds), then also no it does not go for environmental causes, you should follow case 1.

But if you mean by "donations of Ramadan" any Sadakat, then the answer is yes, you can pay it for planting trees or any other public welfare purpose. But remember, you will still be liable to pay Zakat Alfetr before the end of Ramadan.

God bless you.

Comment: Improving posts by editing is a fundamental aspect of the Stack Exchange model (see: http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/editing) If you have a valid reason for rolling back my edits, feel free to bring it up on [meta] where it can be discussed rationally; otherwise, all your rollback appears to have done was reintroduce myriad grammar and spelling errors, reintroduce the greeting that you've already been told is not welcome here, and generally make it harder to read due to sloppy formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

- you cannnot give zakat to this because it is not of the 8 masaref Allah defined.
- When you give money or when you decide to do anything good,  wisely select the thing that will gain you more hasanat...
  Saying that, please know that some actions are more appreciated by Allah than others, like watering, one of the best things one can do.

Advise: Try to save souls, some people die because they do not find what we spend on coffee.

Comment: I need reference on how can we give sadaqaat to this purpose?